# Nginx letsencrypt configuration slow

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx, cron

Nginx should be configured properly using letsencrypt but running slow `404.8ms` for the SSL segment. Is there a way to reconfigure Nginx to reduce this time or should I get a ca that is closer to my server or possibly a new vendor?

I am using DigitalOcean New York -1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

[ssl test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8B6o.png)

Since I saw this question asked a lot with no real answers. I think its important to realize some SSL speed testers will lump other uncontrollable SSL connections into your sites SSL speed.  I realized my controllable SSL connection time was 124ms first connection and 21ms after but Yandex + Purechat were constantly 202ms.

I would have deleted this question but I feel like it might help someone else.